# Android afreechart customize XY Quadrants

Tags: android, charts

Here is my problem:

I am using `AFreeChart` to display a chart in my `activity`. I am giving only positive inputs to my graph.

So I wanted to show my graph only in

- (X,Y) Quadrant not in (X,-Y) Quadrant
- (-X,Y) Quadrant and (-X,-Y) Quadrant

Is there any possibility to limit quadrants?.

Can anyone please tell me is there any way to customize Quadrants in AFreeChart?

Answer (score 0):

You need to force the range values for the axes to be positive in order to achieve this, you can set the lowerLimit for your range as 0.0 and upper to the maximum value. Something like below,

```
axis.setRange(0.0, <+upper limit value>);
```